# How can I achieve Disaster Recovery (DR) in simple recovery model

Tags: sql-server-2008, disaster-recovery

**One of my client do not want any change in existing SQL Server 2008, which has 42 Databases (around 70 GB total size) and all databases are in simple recovery mode.

I need to replicate data for Disaster Recovery in same scenario. The acceptable downtime with data loss is 30 minuets.
How can i do this, plz help.. !**

Comment: This is RTO 30 minutes. what is your client's RPO i.e recovery point objective ,,,, How much data your client is willing to lose in case of a disaster ??? What sql server edition your client has ??

Comment: Hi M.Ali, yes RTO is 30 minutes. As i said my client agreed to lose 30 minutes data in case of a disaster. He is using SQL 2008..  What do u think Ali, how can i do this?

Comment: That's version of sql server, 2008 I was asking what edition they have ,,, standard, enterprise or datacenter or any other ???

Comment: oh! it is Enterprise Edition M.Ali

Comment: Great in this case "Asynchronous Mirroring" is the way to go, you will have no downtime at all, and data loss is a split second maybe, not more than a second though. And this feature is only available in enterprise edition.

Comment: Thanks Ali, I was thinking about the same. Since it is the only available option in this scenario, in simple recovery mode. By the way, I am also thinking about differential backup every 30 Minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Switch to Full recovery mode and implement [log shipping](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187103%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- Implement [mirroring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
- If neither is practical, do full backups nightly, and [differential](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175526%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) backups every 30 minutes, ship them to your standby.

No matter what solution you go with, test the recovery process to make sure it meats the RTO, and make sure your SQL servers are licensed properly.

Comment: I think differential backup would be perfect match and very simple to deploy. I'll schedule differential backup every 30 minutes and in midnight, the last differential backup will be transferred to standby server and there a restore script will restore all databases... am i right SqlACID ? any suggestion or if & buts ?

Comment: You still need to do full backups (nightly? weekly?), so in a recovery situation you would restore the most recent full and most recent differential; and there's no predicting how big the diffs will be without knowing how much data changes. And if 42 databases turns in to 400, managing it all can be a pain. Log shipping is better, no full db restore in recovery, but you have to continually apply logs.

Comment: Yes! you are right. Log Shipping is better. I'll convince my client for log shipping but meanwhile i am going to give 'diff backup solution' to him. 

Thanks SqlACID!